# Display two different maps with different layers in one layout in PyQGIS? Problem with .pdf export

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layouts, maps

I would like to export a .pdf with 2 maps (with different layers).
However, some layers do not appear in the map items!

I'd like:

- In the first map: the shapefile over the raster 1, and these two over the basemap (A300 + Area1 + basemap)
- In the second map: the shapefile over the raster 2, and these two over the basemap (A300 + Area2 + basemap)

Everything appears fine in the layout view (see image left) but in the .pdf only the basemap appears (see image right)! What is wrong? here is my code

```py
import os
import processing
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import qgis.utils
import shutil
from qgis.PyQt import QtGui


project = QgsProject.instance()
project.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(21781))

iface.mainWindow().blockSignals(True)

# add basemap (raster)
basemap = "C:\\MyData\\LK25.vrt"
basemap_r = iface.addRasterLayer(basemap , "my_basemap")
basemap_r.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(2056))

# add vector layer
shplayer = iface.addVectorLayer("C:\\MyData\\A300.shp", "A300", "ogr")
shplayer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(2056))
project.addMapLayer(shplayer)

# add raster layer 1
rlayer1 = iface.addRasterLayer("C:\\MyData\\Area_1.asc", "Area1")
rlayer1.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(2056))
project.addMapLayer(rlayer1)

# add raster layer 2
rlayer2 = iface.addRasterLayer("C:\\MyData\\Area_2.asc", "Area2")
rlayer2.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(2056))
project.addMapLayer(rlayer2)


#-- Create custom caneva
manager = project.layoutManager()
layout_name = 'my_custom_layout'
layout_list = manager.printLayouts()

layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.setName(layout_name)
layout.initializeDefaults()
manager.addLayout(layout)

#--- create map item 1 (shapefile, raster 1, basemap)

map1 = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout) # create Layout item
map1.setRect(QRectF(10, 10, 210, 90)) # set the map item rectangle
map1.setPos(10,10) # map item upper left corner position
map1.setFrameEnabled(True) # to have a map black border

map1.setLayers([shplayer, rlayer1, basemap_r]) # set layers to be mapped
map1_extent = QgsRectangle(rlayer1.extent())
map1_extent.scale(1.0)
map1.setExtent(map1_extent)

layout.addLayoutItem(map1)
map1.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(10,10))
map1.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(210,90))


#--- create map item 2 (shapefile, raster 2, basemap)

map2 = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
map2.setRect(QRectF(10, 110, 210, 90))
map2.setPos(10,110) 
map2.setFrameEnabled(True)

map2.setLayers([shplayer, rlayer1, basemap_r])
map2.setExtent(map1_extent)

layout.addLayoutItem(map2)
map2.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(10,110, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
map2.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(210,90,QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))

layout.refresh()
project.write()

# export map in .pdf
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
exporter.exportToPdf("C:\\qgs2.pdf", QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
```

[image]

Comment: try changing the loading order of the layers https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapSettings.html#a2bd2b940e1db7812d638da28caabd62a

Comment: I tried both orders and it does not work :-( The documentation says that the first layer in the list will be on the top, so the order of my list should be fine. I tried to take out the underlaying map, and there, none of my two other layers appear! Do you have another hint?

Comment: OK at the end I found out that the layers where in another coordinate system than the base map, that's why they did not appear here... sorry

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually using your "ms" variable anyway, so setting the layers there has no effect...

What you need to do is call map.setLayers(). See https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.8/core/QgsLayoutItemMap.html#qgis.core.QgsLayoutItemMap.setLayers

Comment: True I haven't see that... sorrry. I changed with  map.setLayers() but it did not solve the problem. I realized that there is a problem in the .pdf export, because the maps render well in the layout, but not in the .pdf. I edited my questions. Do you have any hints why?